# Get last tweet Twitter api

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I try to show the last tweet from a specif user, using the Twitter API. When I try to echo the first result I get an empty page. When I echo my JSON data is see [this](https:///screensystem.nl/twitter.php).

I have the following PHP script:

```
<?php

require "Twitteroauth/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumer_key = "";
$consumer_secret = "";
$access_token = "";
$access_token_secret = "";


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

$statuses = $connection->get("statuses/user_timeline", ["screen_name" => "NS_online"], ["lang" => "NL"]);
//var_dump($statuses);
// get your json as an associative array
$jsonArray = json_decode($statuses, true);

print_r($jsonArray);

$test = $jsonArray[0]->created_at;

echo $test;

?>
```

Comment: What is the result of your http request?

Comment: This is the result: https://screensystem.nl/twitter.php

Comment: You get a JSON response, so you should probably `json_decode()` it, not `json_encode()`.

Comment: also reference by $jsonArray[0]->created_at

Comment: also `print_r($jsonArray)` instead of `echo $jsonArray;`

Comment: I have update my code, but it still not working.

Comment: "_but it still not working_" meaning what exactly? White page? Wrong timeline? Showing a random tweet?

Comment: @kerbholz I get a white page.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Since you're using Abraham's TwitterAPI you don't get a JSON response but already an array. No need to `json_decode()`. Just use `print_r($statuses); $test = $statuses[0]->created_at;` after `$statuses  = $connection->get`